# Polygon destroys python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder, shapely

I have the following very simple code that I run in Spyder. But everytime I execute it as test(0), Python says "
Restarting kernel... " and no output is produced

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

def test(x):
    p = Polygon([[x, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1], [0, 0]])
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

This problem only seems to originate from the construction of this polygon.

Comment: That polygon is not closed.  Does your API expect the Python to be closed?  Even if it were closed, the area is 1.  You have a long handle with 0 area.

Comment: I can even forget about the area, the problem still exists. Isn't it precisely closed by having [0,0] twice in there?

Comment: Try running this in a regular Python session instead of through your IDE and see what happens.

Comment: this problem somehow only exists in my IDE, the question however is. What might be causing this?

Comment: Runs smoothly in Spyder 5.0.0, kernel 3.6.10.

Comment: To close it, the last point must be the same as the first point.  I doubt that's the issue here.

Comment: I think this is an installation issue with Shapely. Please see the second part of [our video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ul79ihg41Rs) to learn how to reinstall Anaconda correctly and use packages from Pip and Conda-forge, in case you need them.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba indeed, i uninstalled and installed that package again and now it works nicely.

Comment: Great! I'm really glad my advice pointed you in the right direction.